# Critique my retagging

Tags: discussion, tags

Nobody seems to offer any feedback on my suggestions, so I'll just come right out and ask for it.   My poorly defined *modus operandi* at present for retagging is that that tags should be about how to **do/play** something ("body of knowledge"; and this is also *why* game tags are good), not simply be about some static/elemental thing.  While I'm still trying to turn my thoughts into a *truly meta-worthy wall-of-text*, I'll try to bait some arguments to see if I'm sane.

Here's a couple recent retags of mine and my rationales:

Added class tags because these questions are about how (class) works.  These tags are also specific ("subtags"), because a sniper in TF2 has nothing to do with a sniper from Battlefield.

- [What are the advantages of using the Huntsman?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2035/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-the-bow-in-team-fortress-2)
- [How can I be a good combat engineer?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27390/how-can-i-be-a-good-combat-engineer)

Didn't add a class tag.  While they're **about** medics/spies, the information is equally valid for all TF2 players, not just *a* class.

- [How can I distinguish which gun a medic is using?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24261/how-can-i-distinguish-which-gun-a-medic-is-using)
- [How to tell if there is a spy on my head?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33584/how-to-tell-if-there-is-a-spy-on-my-head)

**I also hate redundant/overbroad tags:**

Removed [accuracy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accuracy), [crouching](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crouching).  Those tags are so broad they are worthless.  As they are fundamental aspects of virtually every other game in the genre, why not [moving](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moving) or [jumping](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jumping).

- [Does crouching improve your aim?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16881/does-crouching-improve-your-aim)
- [Does crouching improve accuracy with most ranged weapons?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28195/does-crouching-improve-accuracy-with-most-ranged-weapons)

Removed [stealth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stealth).  Redundant with it being tagged as spy (should be tf2-spy), as it is an absolutely essential mechanic of the overarching tag.

- [How do you avoid bumping into players as a spy?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3184/how-do-you-avoid-bumping-into-players-as-a-spy)

Furthermore, by this logic I abhor most uses of [weapons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons), e.g. [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/20104/revisions).  *All* soldiers use weapons and in TF2 that's pretty much how classes are defined, so what's the tag really add (when in doubt, throw it out)?

Comment: I'm actually pretty much in agreement with the choices you've made for these questions. Especially the accuracy/crouching ones, and the decision on not using class tags on those two specific questions.

Comment: That all sounds good to me.